# Best practices for coding a module based website?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a website that is header, content, footer. The content section is broken up into two columns. (for now) In these columns are modules.  The modules can be varying heights and varying widths. The client would like the modules to be different heights and widths as they see fit and then mixed and matched to look best.  What would be an ideal way to go about coding this?  Make a bunch of different width containers and float them left? Then the client can choose the appropriate container?

Must work in all browsers including IE7+

Comment: When you say mixed and matched, do you mean through some sort of client-side drag-and-drop feature?  Or mixed and matched via an email to you, so you re-organize the homepage to have the X, Y and Z modules organized a certain way?

Also, what would be the alternative to "different width containers floated left"? Tables?  Unless I'm missing something, seems as if the question's already been answered by the asker.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use a content management system or not, I would recommend to pick a Grid System for you CSS. There are a few different options and all are aimed at precisely defining blocks (modules) and tend to be cross-browser compatible.

You can find some examples at http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/